# ProgressDialog freezes in async task

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask, freeze

I am reading lat/lon from file, creating polygon and adding it to the map in `AsyncTask`. Everything is working fine - except `progressDialog` allways freezes at start of the action and dismissed after action is completed.This is my code:

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
   private class shpLoading extends AsyncTask<GoogleMap, List<LatLng>, String> {
              private ProgressDialog dialog;
              private String path; 
                      private int loaded;
              public void setPath(String p){
                     this.path = p;   
              }

              @Override
              protected String doInBackground(GoogleMap... params) {    

                    final ShpReader shpRead = new ShpReader();



                        try {
                            shpRead.read(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvalidShapeFileException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                          dialog.setMax(shpRead.daugiakampiai().size());
                          int i = 0;
                          for(List<LatLng> a: shpRead.polygons()){                                                            
                              function.arAntLinijos(a);
                              for(int h = 0; h < a.size()-1; h++){
                                  LatLng point = function.midPoint(a.get(h), a.get(h+1));
                                  a.add(h+1, point);
                                  h++; 

                                  if(i > 3000){
                                      message("You reached max count!");
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }
                              publishProgress(a);

                              i++;                           
                          }

                    return "Done";
              } 
                  @Override
              protected void onPreExecute() {                                                                         
                      dialog = new ProgressDialog(Measuring.this);   
                      dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL); 
                      dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
                      dialog.setCancelable(false);
                      dialog.setProgress(0);                         
                      dialog.show();
              }                                       
              }

              @Override
              protected void onProgressUpdate(List<LatLng>... values) {
                            dialog.setProgress(loaded++);
                Polygon daug = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                  .addAll(values[0])
                  .strokeWidth(1)
                  .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                  .fillColor(0x3F00FF00));

                  plotai.add(new Polygons(db.getMaxFieldID()+1, daug)); 
                  daug = null;                               
                }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

              }                      
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you should draw your polygons not in `onProgressUpdate` method, but in `doInBackground` method. In `onProgressUpdate` method you have to update progress in your `ProgressDialog` object (in your code `ProgressDialog` is showed, but not updated its progress at all).

Comment: I was drawing them and in `doInBackground` using handler - same result

Comment: in onProgressUpdate method add "dialog.setProgress(progressValue)", where progressValue would be current loading progress (ex.: in percents)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't works too. Progress bar freezes at 0 and at end directly jumps to 100%

Comment: Okey, its worked, my mistake, `dialog.setProgress(progressValue)` helped. Thank you!

Comment: But it is still very laggy. Progress bar doesn't increases smoothly, but for example - jumps to 30%, waits, jumps to 90%, waits again and than finishes.

Comment: instead of "dialog.setProgress(loaded++);" use "dialog.setProgess((currentPolygonNumber * 100) / totalPolygonsCount);". And - in onProgressUpdate should be just 1 instruction "dialog.setProgress(...)", all calculations should be placed in doInBackground method. Your are doing too much work in onProgressUpdate method, which runs in UI thread and slows your programm. Making work in UI thread is worst thing what you can do. All calculations should be executed in background threads.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39888/discussion-between-veaceslav-gaidarji-and-eddwhis)